# SilverStripe Admin Changes

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am trying to add new settings page and emails page. When you click on emails menu, it is under silverstripe admin cms but After reloading Emails page, it is not under silverstripe admin cms.

So what is the reason it is not under admin cms ?

Here is controller code:

```
public function index() {
    $getmem=Member::currentUser();
    if($getmem->RainloopEmail !='' && $getmem->Pass !='')
    {
        $com=$getmem->RainloopEmail.":".$getmem->Pass;
        $encrypted = base64_encode($getmem->RainloopEmail) ;
        $rainloopemail=$encrypted;
        $encrypted =base64_encode($getmem->Pass);
        $pss=$encrypted;

        $hash=base64_encode($com);

    }
    else
    {
        $rainloopemail='';
        $pss='';
        $com=$getmem->RainloopEmail.":".$getmem->Pass;
        $hash=base64_encode($com);

    }
    $url='http://op.mctitsolutions.com/rainloop/rainloop.php?hash='.$hash;
    $arrayData = new ArrayData(array(
'Width' => '100%',
'Height' => '100%',
'Location'=>$url ));

return $arrayData->renderWith(Array('EmailsAdminController_Content','Coach_message','Page'));

}
```

And here is template file code:

```
<div style="padding:55px 20px">
$EditForm
<iframe  id="MainPopupIframe"  width="$Width" height="605px" src="$Location"></iframe>
```

So what is the reason it is not under admin cms ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @3dgoo why minus vote ? question added ?

Comment: I did not down vote your question. 
I can only make guesses as to why your question was down voted. 
Here is what I think some of the problems with your question are. Hopefully you find this useful in trying to improve your question.

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. It is not clear what your problem or question is. Try to write a simple example of the issue with the minimum amount of code s that others can recreate the issue. State what you are trying to do, what result you expect, what result you are getting and show what you have tried to overcome this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer.

Added new function in controller. and loop used for displaying in template file. this solved my problem.

```
public function getViewEmails() {
    $hash='';
            $getmem=Member::currentUser();
    if($getmem->RainloopEmail !='' && $getmem->Pass !='')
    {
        $com=$getmem->RainloopEmail.":".$getmem->Pass;
        $encrypted = base64_encode($getmem->RainloopEmail) ;
        $rainloopemail=$encrypted;
        $encrypted =base64_encode($getmem->Pass);
        $pss=$encrypted;

        $hash=base64_encode($com);

    }
    else
    {
        $rainloopemail='';
        $pss='';
        $com=$getmem->RainloopEmail.":".$getmem->Pass;
        $hash=base64_encode($com);

    }
    $url='http://op.mctitsolutions.com/rainloop/rainloop.php?hash='.$hash;
        return new ArrayList(array(
                new ArrayData(array(
                        'Url'=>$url,
                        'Width' => '100%',
                ))
        ));
}
```

Here is my template file.

```
<div style="padding:55px 20px">

<% loop ViewEmails %>
<iframe  id="MainPopupIframe"  width="$Width" height="605px" src="$Url">
 </iframe>
   <% end_loop %>
</div>
```